# jquery ajax requires second click before form data is inserted into database through php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have looked through the other questions relating to this and i am not able to find an answer that fixes my issue.

When i click the button to post the form data to the php file where it is validated and if it passes validation will then put it in the database, it does the validation ok and gives the errors if there are any on the first click but if there are no errors it does nothing and requires a second click to then put the data into the database?

I have tried both document.ready, #item.click and even put the #item.click inside a document.ready function none of which solved the issue.

Below is both the jquery and php that deals with this, if someone could point me in the right direction i would very much appreciate it.

Jquery

```
$("#postcomment").click(function() {

    var Name = $("input#name").val();
    var Comment = $("textarea#comment").val()

    $("form").submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
        url: 'comment.php',
        data: { name: Name, comment: Comment}, 
        type: 'POST'
        });

    });
});
```

PHP

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['comment'] = $_POST['comment'];

$ipaddy = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(Input::exists()){
    $name  = trim (escape($_POST['name']));
    $comment = trim (escape($_POST['comment']));

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 5,
            'max' => 50),
        'comment' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 10,
            'max' => 200)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()){

        $insCom = "INSERT INTO comments (name, comment, commentdate, ip) VALUES ('$name', '$comment', NOW(), '$ipaddy')";

        if($insCom = $db->query($insCom)){
            Session::flash('home', 'successfull');
                Redirect::to('test.php');
        } else {
            Session::flash('home', 'unsuccessfull');
                Redirect::to('test.php');
        }

    }else{
        foreach($validate->errors() as $error){
            Session::flash('home', $error, '<br>');
                Redirect::to('test.php');
        }
    }        
}
```

HTML for the form @Yorick

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" action="" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
        <div style="height:30px"></div>
    <label for="name">Comment:</label><br />
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="comment" rows="5" cols="60" maxlength="200"></textarea>
        <br />
    <div id="btm">
        <button id="postcomment">Post Comment</button>
        <div id="sflash">
        <?php
        if(Session::exists('home')) {
            echo '<p>', Session::flash('home'), '</p>';
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: yes its part of the init.php file that is included at the very top, i didn't include it in the code above is all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
}
```

The default type for a  is submit, so whenever you click on it you are handling the click event and performing an ajax call and then the browser is submitting the form for you afterwards.

If you look at the network trace on the browser debugging console you will see this.

Set the  type="button" to avoid this. Also return false from your .click() handler to stop the click from propagating as you handled it completely.

The $("form") really isn't needed and is just causing yet another form submission.

You definitely need to install your .click() handler inside a $(document).ready(...) construct.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well for the <form> and contents.

Comment: i've added it @yorick, its messy but its just for testing purposes

Comment: This is as far as I got with testing, which shows that the form is submitted just the once if you get it right. http://jsfiddle.net/y2omyy8r/7/

Comment: thanks for the try but it didnt work, i think im going to try a different way of going about getting field text back in the text fields after page refresh through php, but thats what i was trying to avoid by using a ajax request lol.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track with the Ajax call. Can you prove that the data is not getting to your PHP and the bug isn't in the PHP code. The sample given is depending on too much private classes to be able to verify that the bug isn't there. try using xdebug or var_dump($_POST) to check whether the Ajax call is working or not. Learn how to use the Network Tab in your Browser Developer Tools to see what is happening.

Comment: iv rewritten it and got it working now by just redoing the way the recaptcha is set on the page with the form along with the php code it self, i know ajax would have been a better way but after 24hours of fooling arund with what should be simple i got impatient @yorick